# Shortcut to wrap highlighted text into a System.out.println() on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, macros

Is there a way to highlight a text and put it into a System.out.println() by using a shortcut on intellij ?

Here's what I'm looking for :
1. I highlight `dog.getName()` using my mouse
2. I use a shortcut
3. Result : `System.out.println(dog.getName());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready to use way/shortcut in Intellij Idea to do this.

I can offer you to ways to reach something similar.

### [Live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html)

Live templates lets you create small code snippets that are expanded by an abbreviation.

Live templates can have variables that are are derived from the context, other variables or just filled by you when inserting the templates.

There are surrounding live templates that only work when code has been selected. In most cases, the selected code is wrapped by the live template.

Intellij offers quite a few ready to use live templates, like `surround with IF` or `surround with try-catch` aso.

A live template for your case looks like this:

```
System.out.println($SELECTION$);$END$
```

You have to save that live template in the `surround` category under `Editor->Live Templates` and assign it a proper abbreviation.

Select the code you want to surround, press `Ctrl+Alt+t` and select the newly created live template or just type the assigned abbreviation. That's it.

### [Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html)

The second way is recording a macro and replay it. 
Furthermore, a shortcut can be assigned to a macros, but is a replay of your typing and this can be a bit slow if you want to input more than just a few characters.

Imports aren't done automatically as well, like they are when using live templates. Therefore, if you want to use a macro for inserting code, you have to use the full qualified class name or optimize imports after running the macro.

I suggest you try out both ways and decide afterwards what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm wondering if it's possible to assign the live template to a custom combination of keys like "alt+s" to have a direct access to it instead of using ctrl+alt+t and choose it ?

Comment: Nope, there is no way to do that. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101364 or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000491850-Key-bindings-for-live-templates